# How to access a file from dropbox which has already been downloaded via dropbox?

Tags: ios, dropbox

I am attempting to integrate Dropbox chooser into my app. I just want to be able to access a file which the user has already downloaded via dropbox. I have the chooser working correctly however the DBChooserResult Returns a link to retrieve the file online. I want to be able to retrieve it directly from the ipad as an option in case there is no current internet access. Is there any way to do this? Also is there anyway to sort the results shown by the DBChooser to only show files of a certain type? eg only show .pdf files?

Part of the reason for the app is because user will be in locations where there is no internet access. I am using dropbox because that is where the user already stores the files in question. I know I could get the user to make sure he downloads the newest copy of the file directly to the app before he leaves the area with wifi, however this seems redundant since the file can be favourited in dropbox to ensure it is always up to date.

Comment: You must cache it yourself. I do not think the chooser will work without internet connection will it?

Comment: @MitchellCurrie - Thats pretty much what I want to know. There doesn't seem to be a lot of examples or anything out there so I'm hoping someone knows something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditionally you must provide a cached list of objects, and store the file in the cache yourself.
NSFileManager and CoreData can help you here.

Try looking at the new SYNC API and examples:
[here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/26/introducing-the-dropbox-sync-api-for-mobile-developers)